# Editing code in Windows but running Rails in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm frustrated with having to develop Rails on Windows.

So, I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on a laptop and remote desktop'ped into it. That works.

All I really want/need to do is to have a Rails server running on Ubuntu. But can I do all the code editing, terminal access etc. from Windows?

In short, is the following possible to do:

1. Code is in some folder in Ubuntu (say `/home/app1`)
2. Using some sort of file sharing (Samba?), I map the `/home/app1` so I can access the folder in Windows.
3. Then I access and edit the code in Windows via the file share.
4. Use some terminal (puTTY?) to do things like `rails server`, run generators etc, tail the log file.
5. Access the Rails site in a browser on Windows.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Ps.** I know I could simply use Ubuntu via the remote desktop, but I don't want to because:

1. Don't like x-windows.
2. Too much of a hassle when cannot Alt+Tab from Remote Desktop to Windows Desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think /home/app1 can be mounted using "mount" (NFS server/client) to a windows directory.

I would rather use ubuntu as VMware virtual machine (or virtual desktop free open source), that is what I am doing right now for Groovy and Grails using Ubuntu 10.10 vmware VM in Windows XP.

Comment: I used Ubuntu on VirtualBox and it's easy folder-sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I do this with PHP (WAMP). Ensure you have these set up:

- Share a folder for editing or reading (I suggest keeping your files on your workstation for faster access).
- Ensure your server does support reading/following symlinks (eg; some Apache versions had issues with this.)
- Ensure server is "online", ie, can be accessed externally.
- Ensure your server software can be controlled (ie through ssh)
- Optionally, ensure it starts automatically (init.d on linux).